# Convert DateTime.Now.Month; as string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
int month=DateTime.Now.Month;
```

It gives output as = 04

But how do I get the month as string 'April' from code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
> ```

For additional hints how to use `ToString` to get another results, this may help: 
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
string month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month);
```

..if you want it in the right culture

Answer (score 2):

@pranay, @gsharp: The `DateTime.ToString(string format)` method respects the current culture.